# Using AVX to improve performance of float subtract, divide, truncate to int32

Tags: c, optimization, avx

Trying to use AVX to improve performance of the following

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl calculate_quantized_vertical_values(long length, float min, float step, float* source, unsigned long* destination)
{           
    for (long i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = (source[i] - min) / step;          
    }       
}
```

by replacing it with

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl calculate_quantized_vertical_values_avx(long length, float min, float step, float* source, unsigned long* destination)
{       
    long multiple8end = ((long)(length / 8)) * 8;

    __m256 min256 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((const float*)&min);
    __m256 step256 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((const float*)&step);

    for (long i = 0; i < multiple8end; i+=8)
    {
        __m256 value256 = _mm256_load_ps((const float*)(source + i));
        __m256 offset256 = _mm256_sub_ps(value256, min256);
        __m256 floatres256 = _mm256_div_ps(offset256, step256);
        __m256i long256 = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(floatres256);
        _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)(destination + i), long256);           
    }

    for (long i = multiple8end; i < length; i ++)
    {
        destination[i] = (source[i] - min) / step;
    }
}
```

The original loop takes around 330ms with my 55M element source array and the contents of the loop compile to

```
loc_180001050:
movss   xmm0, dword ptr [r10+rcx-4]
subss   xmm0, xmm3
divss   xmm0, xmm2
cvttss2si rax, xmm0
mov     [rcx-4], eax
movss   xmm1, dword ptr [r10+rcx]
subss   xmm1, xmm3
divss   xmm1, xmm2
cvttss2si rax, xmm1
mov     [rcx], eax
movss   xmm0, dword ptr [r10+rcx+4]
subss   xmm0, xmm3
divss   xmm0, xmm2
cvttss2si rax, xmm0
mov     [rcx+4], eax
movss   xmm1, dword ptr [r10+rcx+8]
subss   xmm1, xmm3
divss   xmm1, xmm2
cvttss2si rax, xmm1
mov     [rcx+8], eax
add     rcx, 10h
sub     r8, 1
jnz     short loc_180001050
```

The AVX loop takes around 170ms over the same 55M element source array and the contents of the (main) loop compile to:

```
loc_180001160:
vmovups ymm0, ymmword ptr [r8+rdx]
lea     rdx, [rdx+20h]
vsubps  ymm1, ymm0, ymm6
vdivps  ymm2, ymm1, ymm7
vcvttps2dq ymm3, ymm2
vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rdx-20h], ymm3
sub     rax, 1
jnz     short loc_180001160
```

So there IS a performance improvement with AVX but I wonder if it's possible to get a more significant performance improvement or this is about the limit for this particular calculation

**Edit:** I should also mention that I'm calling these DLL functions from a .NET app if it makes any difference.

**Edit:** I would ideally want `unsigned char` array for `destination` but sticking with `int32` for now because I've not found a way to do the `float` -> `unsigned char` conversion with AVX

Also multiplication by `1.f/step` instead of division by `step` should be fine for me if it improves performance

Comment: `_mm256_cvttps_epi32` will convert to signed `int32`, your signature indicates that you want `unsigned long` as output, is that intended? (I would avoid `long` here anyway -- on linux 64bit systems that would be 64 bits wide, in case you ever want to port this). Do you actually need to use division or could you multiply by `1.f/step` instead?

Comment: @chtz, I've updated the question. Got your point about long vs int32, unlikely I'll be porting to Linux, but I'll update that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you scale by `1/step` instead of dividing by `step` you should be significantly faster, unless you are limited by memory-throughput. If you factor out the subtraction of `min`, you are also able to use FMA instructions, if they are available:

```
void calculate_quantized_vertical_values_avx(size_t length, float min, float step, float* source, uint32_t* destination)
{       
    size_t multiple8end = ((length / 8)) * 8;
    const float scale = 1.f/step;
    const float offset = -min * scale;
    const __m256 scale256 = _mm256_set1_ps(scale);
    const __m256 offset256 = _mm256_set1_ps(offset);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < multiple8end; i+=8)
    {
        __m256 value256 = _mm256_load_ps((const float*)(source + i));
#ifdef __FMA__
        __m256 floatres256 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(value256, scale256, offset256);
#else
        __m256 floatres256 = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(value256, scale256), offset256); 
#endif
        __m256i long256 = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(floatres256);
        _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)(destination + i), long256);           
    }

    for (size_t i = multiple8end; i < length; i ++)
    {
        destination[i] = (source[i] * scale) + offset;
    }
}
```

If you want to convert the result to `uint8`, have a look at `_mm256_packus_epi32` and `_mm256_packus_epi16` (or `_mm_packus_epi32` and `_mm_packus_epi16` if you don't have AVX2).

Comment: @axk: to get data in the right order after packing 4 vectors down to 4x 8-byte chunks, you're going to want `vpermq`.  AVX2 pack instructions are really inconvenient "in-lane" shuffles.

Comment: Unfortunately replacing division with multiplication didn't help at all, I guess it's memory-bound in my case, I tried just copying the data and it takes the same time. Now with 800MHz DDR3 at 6.4GB/s peak throughput and reading/writing 220Mb in 120ms (multithreaded) comes out to be 3.7GB/s.

Comment: I guess maybe if I "interleaved" the source and destination it could give a slight improvement because it won't have to go back and forth so often between far-apart memory blocks?

Comment: I doubt that interleaving source and destination will help. Overwriting the source with the destination might help. Also, compressing `4x8 int32` to `32 uint8` on-the-fly could help. Ideally, you are able to pipeline whatever code generates your source values into the same loop (thus avoiding to store that source at all). Or generate only blocks which fit in (half of) L1 cache, convert them and then generate the next block. You should post another question for that, though.